# How do I convert an int to two bytes in C#?

Tags: c#, byte, int

How do I convert an int to two bytes in C#?

Comment: Which part of the int? Two bytes are not enough to encode a whole 32-bit integer value.

Comment: `int` requires 4 bytes for storage. Do you wish to lose the information in the MSBs?

Comment: Who the *beep* downvoted this. This is a useful and interesting question as the C way suddenly doesn't work for no good reason in C# and the obvious APIs don't exist (BitConverter is slow and *broken* in many ways).

Comment: @Joshua the c ways work if you switch to "unsafe" c#

Comment: @Joshua: It may, or may not, be useful and interesting but it's also poorly specified. The question suggests an `int`/`Int32`, in which case does the OP want the most-sig pair? the least-sig pair? some of each? some sort of esoteric xor-ing? I didn't downvote, yet...

Comment: I interpreted it as needing to write a file format that specified 2 byte integer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you just want the low bytes:

```
byte b0 = (byte)i,
     b1 = (byte)(i>>8);
```

However, since 'int' is 'Int32' that leaves 2 more bytes uncaptured.

Comment: This is my solution. Much must faster than BitConverter.

Comment: @Joshua, I did a quick bench-mark (Release build, 50000000 iterations, Stopwatch and full test repeated twice to remove various artifacts) and the difference between creating an array and using the bit-masking vs. calling BitConverter is approximately 1ns per call on my machine.  If you remove the array creation (just get the two bytes), the difference is about 14ns.

Comment: I don't doubt your benchmarks. BitConverter is slow in comparison because it has to allocate arrays. If I can pre-detect my array size for thousands of integers I can save a nontrivial amount of time.

Comment: @Joshua, non-trivial is, of course, relative.  At a 14ns difference, you'll have to execute 1 million iterations to observe a 14ms delay from the extra array allocation.  Memory allocation for small temporary objects by the CLR is actually quite cheap.  This is a consequence of the garbage collector design, which compacts the heap during collection, allowing allocation without requiring handling of fragmentation.

Comment: Try it on mono, get burned. Not that most people care.

Comment: @Joshua - it isn't Mono that is the issue - it is different-endianness. The shift approach side-steps this completely (I assume the Mono comment was aimed at BitConverter, not shift?)

Comment: Can we note that this is pretty language-independent?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [BitConverter.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) to get the bytes comprising an Int32.  There will be 4 bytes in the result, however, not 2.

Answer (score 4):

Is it an int16?

```
Int16 i = 7;
byte[] ba = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
```

This will only have two bytes in it.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it, although not as slick as other methods:

```
Int32 i = 38633;
byte b0 = (byte)(i % 256);
byte b1 = (byte)(i / 256);
```

Comment: can you please explain how to get back the integer from 2 bytes using this solution

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
```

Option 2:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2];

buffer[0] = (byte) number;
buffer[1] = (byte)(number >> 8);
```

I prefer option 1!