# What does it mean two byte sum

Tags: c#, arrays, sum, byte

I have an array of bytes.

```
byte[] ar = new array{1,2,3,4,5}
```

I have to calculate summary;

```
sum = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15;
```

But result must be two bytes. What does it mean two bytes result? How can I get two bytes sum?

Comment: Literally two bytes (`byte[]`)? Or a 16-bit integer ([`short`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#characteristics-of-the-integral-types))?

Comment: I dont know. The task said "result on 2 bytes"

Comment: You should probably clarify that with whoever assigned you this task then. I don't think anyone here can answer that

Comment: If it's two bytes (`byte[]`), then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3919804/5803406

Answer (score 0):

I find answer byte b0 = (byte)i, b1 = (byte)(i>>8); but in anather task was get 4 byte sum. What does it mean? b2 = (byte)(i>>16); b3 = (byte)(i>>24) is it right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` of `linq` and convert to `int` inside select

Example:

```
int sum = ar.Select(x => (int)x).Sum();
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Comment: Though `int` is 4 bytes.